Fetch the top 5 efficient query plans for a specific object in SQL Server
I am trying to analyze the performance of different query execution plans for a specific object in SQL Server. My goal is to retrieve the top 5 most efficient query plans so that I can compare them manually and select the best one to force.
Context
Database: SQL Server
Object: [Specify stored procedure]
Current Approach: I have been using the Query Store feature, but I am unsure how to filter and rank the plans effectively.
What I have tried:
I have attempted to use the following SQL query to retrieve execution plans, but I am not getting the desired results:
 SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id), qp.plan_id, qt.query_sql_text, q.query_id, q.query_text_id,
      qp.query_plan, q.avg_compile_memory_kb / 1024 AS avg_compile_memory_mb, q.last_execution_time
FROM sys.query_store_query_text qt
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON qt.query_text_id = q.query_text_id
INNER JOIN sys.query_store_plan qp ON qp.query_id = q.query_id
WHERE ISNULL(OBJECT_NAME(q.object_id), 'N/A') = 'axsp_upd_credit_utilisation2'  -- Filter for specific object
  AND qt.query_sql_text LIKE '%(@includeResidualValue bit%' 
ORDER BY q.last_execution_time DESC;

Questions

How can I modify this query to ensure I am fetching the most
efficient plans based on multiple performance metrics?
Are there specific conditions or filters I should consider adding to
narrow down the results effectively?
What is the best way to force a specific execution plan once I have
identified the most efficient one?

Additional Information
I am looking for best practices in SQL Server regarding execution plan analysis.
Any insights on using the Query Store effectively for this purpose would be greatly appreciated.
Please review the modified SQL I created based on @Charlieface's suggestion. Can you confirm if it is correct and serves its purpose's purpose?
SELECT
    o.name AS ObjectName,
    qp.plan_id,
    qt.query_sql_text,
    q.query_id,
    q.query_text_id,
    qp.query_plan,
    SUM(q.avg_compile_memory_kb) / 1024 AS total_compile_memory_mb,  -- Aggregate memory usage
    MAX(q.last_execution_time) AS last_execution_time,
    qsr.execution_type,
    AVG(qsr.avg_duration) AS avg_duration,
    AVG(qsr.avg_cpu_time) AS avg_cpu_time,
    AVG(qsr.avg_logical_io_reads) AS avg_logical_io_reads,
    AVG(qsr.avg_physical_io_reads) AS avg_physical_io_reads,
    SUM(qsr.count_executions) AS total_executions
FROM sys.query_store_query_text qt
JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON qt.query_text_id = q.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qp ON qp.query_id = q.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsr ON qsr.plan_id = qp.plan_id
JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = q.object_id
WHERE o.name = 'axsp_upd_credit_utilisation2'  -- Filter for specific object
  AND qt.query_sql_text LIKE '%(@includeResidualValue bit%'  -- Filter for specific SQL text
GROUP BY
    o.name,
    qp.plan_id,
    qt.query_sql_text,
    q.query_id,
    q.query_text_id,
    qp.query_plan,
    qsr.execution_type
ORDER BY
    q.query_id,
    qsr.execution_type,  -- Regular execution first
    avg_duration;  -- Order by average duration

Based on the SQL results we received, could you help us determine the best plan to implement? I am inclined to go with the highlighted option, but I would like to seek input from a larger forum for confirmation.


You can use the sys.query_store_runtime_stats view to get runtime statistics for each plan. You can for example order by the avg_duration column.
SELECT
  o.name,
  qp.plan_id,
  qt.query_sql_text,
  q.query_id,
  q.query_text_id,
  qp.query_plan,
  q.avg_compile_memory_kb / 1024 AS avg_compile_memory_mb,
  q.last_execution_time,
  qsr.*
FROM sys.query_store_query_text qt
JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON qt.query_text_id = q.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qp ON qp.query_id = q.query_id
JOIN sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsr ON qsr.plan_id = qp.plan_id
JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = q.object_id
WHERE o.name = 'axsp_upd_credit_utilisation2'  -- Filter for specific object
  AND qt.query_sql_text LIKE '%(@includeResidualValue bit%' 
ORDER BY
  q.query_id,
  sqr.execution_type,  -- regular exec first
  sqr.avg_duration;

Note that this table:

It is unique only for the past runtime statistics intervals. For currently active interval, there may be multiple rows representing runtime statistics for the plan referenced by plan_id, with the execution type represented by execution_type. Typically, one row represents runtime statistics that are flushed to disk, while other(s) represent in-memory state. Hence, to get actual state for every interval you need to aggregate metrics, grouping by plan_id, execution_type and runtime_stats_interval_id.


Regarding your new modified query: rather than doing a giant inefficient GROUP BY, put the calculations into an APPLY or JOIN.
SUM(q.avg_compile_memory_kb) / 1024 AS total_compile_memory_mb is nonsense, it's going to sum up rows which might represent the same plan multiple times. You probably want AVG.
It probably doesn't make sense to look at average statistics for runs that did not complete, only for regular runs.
SELECT
    o.name AS ObjectName,
    qp.plan_id,
    qt.query_sql_text,
    q.query_id,
    q.query_text_id,
    qp.query_plan,
    q.avg_compile_memory_kb / 1024 AS total_compile_memory_mb,  -- Aggregate memory usage
    q.last_execution_time AS last_execution_time,
    qsr.*
FROM sys.query_store_query_text qt
JOIN sys.query_store_query q ON qt.query_text_id = q.query_text_id
JOIN sys.query_store_plan qp ON qp.query_id = q.query_id
JOIN sys.objects o ON o.object_id = q.object_id
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
      AVG(qsr.avg_duration) AS avg_duration,
      AVG(qsr.avg_cpu_time) AS avg_cpu_time,
      AVG(qsr.avg_logical_io_reads) AS avg_logical_io_reads,
      AVG(qsr.avg_physical_io_reads) AS avg_physical_io_reads,
      SUM(qsr.count_executions) AS total_executions
    FROM sys.query_store_runtime_stats qsr
    WHERE qsr.plan_id = qp.plan_id
      AND qsr.execution_type = 0  -- Regular execution only
    GROUP BY
      qsr.execution_type
) qsr
WHERE o.name = 'axsp_upd_credit_utilisation2'  -- Filter for specific object
  AND qt.query_sql_text LIKE '%(@includeResidualValue bit%'  -- Filter for specific SQL text
ORDER BY
    q.query_id,
    avg_duration;  -- Order by average duration


could you help review this? I implemented your suggestions to find the top five efficient plans that execute the same query in the least time, but I can't fit the entire query in the comment section.

Please find link here https://dbfiddle.uk/At0TGXRu

I conducted some analysis with the results, focusing on filtration based on duration. Are there any additional filters we could apply to bring the most efficient and usable plans to the top of the results, ensuring they can be effectively utilized and enforced?
